# React router dom push state causes subsequent pop events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

During the process of integrating Analytics on a React web application I noticed that every time a `history.push(...)` is invoked I get three history change events: the actual PUSH and then two POP events, all of them with the same key.

The application is written in React and uses `react-router-dom` *BrowserRouter* component.

The thing that is the most strange to me is that the three events share the same path and key.

I've captured them with a listener on the history prop and printed resulting action and location to the console and the result is the following:

```
PUSH {pathname: "/projects/portfolio/items", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "g1ct47"}
POP  {pathname: "/projects/portfolio/items", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "g1ct47"}
POP  {pathname: "/projects/portfolio/items", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "g1ct47"}
```

Since the project is pretty big I've tried to concentrate on the simplest case possible in the application, and removed all unnecessary parts to it (other `Route`, `Redirect` components, etc) but the result is always the same.

This feels like a systemic problem with the application itself but I have no other idea about what to look for in the debugging.

---

React Router versions used:

- [`react-router@5.1.2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router)
- [`react-router-dom@^5.0.1`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)

---

App entrypoint where the capture takes place:

```js
function providers = (Component) => {
  const listener = (props) => {
    props.history.listen((location, action) => console.log(action, location))
  }

  return (
    <Provider ... >
      <PersistGate ... >
        <IntlProvider ... >
          <BrowserRouter>
            <ErrorBoundary>
              <>
                <Route
                  path='/' render={listener}
                />
                <Component />
              </>
            </ErrorBoundary>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </IntlProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}
const app = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(providers(MyApp), app)
```

Comment: First of all check your file with routes list. Maybe it re-renders 3 times.

Comment: There are actually three renders, the app is based no redux and different providers, thus when navigating many props happen to change, nonetheless I'd expect the events from the listener to be same.

Comment: maybe u mixed different version of router. Check this https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4059

Comment: I've already read the thread but couldn't find anything useful, as for the version I'm editing the question with further information but I'm using the same major version: `react-router-dom@^5.0.1` and `react-router@5.1.2`.

Comment: try version 4. Version 5 was released couple days ago

Comment: mmmh version 5.2.0 was realeased two months ago, are we speaking about the same library?